# by clicking method in component I want how to render another component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ngoninit

I have two different components

first.component.ts

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 
  setStatusOfUser(){
    this.Service.setStatus(Id,userId).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.msg=data;
    })
   
  }
```

second.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.getProgress()
  }
  getProgress(){
    this.service1.getProgress().subscribe(data=>{
      this.progresss=data;
      
    });
 
   }
```

when I am refrshing the page its working but when  clicking  on the setStatusofUser  I want to render the get progress method in another component how to do that.

Comment: Why you dont create a service to share data between these 2 components?

Answer (score 0):

**first.component.ts**

You can use ViewChild Annotation to call a method in another component

```
@ViewChild(SecondComponent) secondComponent!: SecondComponent;

setStatusOfUser(){
this.secondComponent.getProgress();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works only on refresh because you call `getProgress()` only once `onInit()`. One possible solution that you can use is to use a service to share info between components.

**Service**

```
  private statusObs = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  setStatus(data: any) {
    this.statusObs.next(data);
  }
  
  getStatus() {
    return this.statusObs;
  }
```

**First Component**

```
  constructor(private communicationService:<YourServiceName>){}

   ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 
  setStatusOfUser(){
    this.Service.setStatus(Id,userId).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.communicationService.setStatus(data); // Pass data to the service
      this.msg=data;
    });
  }
```

**Second Component**

```
  constructor(private communicationService:<YourServiceName>){}

  ngOnInit():void {
     this.communicationService.getStatus().subscribe( status => {
        // We used BehaviorSubject<any>(null) with initial value null
        // so use this null check to avoid calling getProcess() in the beggining
        if (status !== null) { // check if your data is the data you want
          this.getProgress();
        }
     });
  }

  getProgress(){
    this.service1.getProgress().subscribe(data=>{
      this.progresss=data;
    });
 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second component...

```
readonly progress$: Service1['getProgress'];

constructor(
  readonly communicationService: CommunicationService,
  readonly service1: Service1
) {
  this.progress$ = this.communicationService.getStatus().pipe(
    filter(status => status !== null),
    switchMap(() => this.service1.getProgress()), // ignore whatever the status is, just get the new progress.
  );
}
```

This will create an observable that, each time the observable from `getStatus` emits, will call `this.service1.getProgress()` and emit whatever that observable returns... until and unless the observable returned by `getStatus` emits again.

Then, in your second component's template, to show it:

```
<div>{{progress$ | asynch}}</div>
```

This will automatically subscribe, update the web page whenever `progress$` emits, and unsubscribe when the component closes.

Comment: If `progress$` emits a complex data structure, change it to also pipe a `share` or `shareReplay` operator so that multiple observables that read from `progress$` will share instead of duplicate what is done inside of `progress$`, and have each thing you want to expose on your web page as separate observables. E.g. `this.percentComplete$ = progress$.pipe(map({percentComplete} => percentComplete))`